# How to add a delay to supervised process in supervisor - linux

Tags: python, linux, cassandra, bottle, supervisord

I added a bottle server that uses python's cassandra library, but it exits with this error: 
 `Bottle     FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)` 
 log shows this:
 `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1765, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)`
So I tried to run it manually using supervisorctl start Bottle ,and then it started with no issue. The conclusion= Bottle service starts too fast (before the needed cassandra supervised service does): a delay is needed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not happy enough with the `sleep` hack I created a startup script and launched `supervisorctl start processname` from there.

```
[program:startup]
command=/startup.sh
startsecs = 0
autostart = true
autorestart = false
startretries = 1
priority=1

[program:myapp]
command=/home/website/venv/bin/gunicorn /home/website/myapp/app.py
autostart=false
autorestart=true
process_name=myapp
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
supervisorctrl start myapp
```

This way supervisor will fire the startup script once and this will start myapp after 5 seconds, mind the `autostart=false` and `autorestart=true` on `myapp`.

Answer (score 30):

This is what I use:

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=bash -c 'sleep 5 && uwsgi /etc/uwsgi.ini'
```

Comment: `command=bash -c "sleep 5 && exec uwsgi /etc/uwsgi.ini"`: exec will replace bash with uwsgi, double quotes will ensure that enclosed string will be sent to bash as a single argument.

Comment: When I do this, the process keeps running in the background after i do "supervisorctl stop"

Comment: @kgreenek Yes, and the previous comment will fix that. Unless your actual program is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where, starting 64 python rq-worker processes using supervisorctl was raising CPU and RAM alert at every restart. What I did was the following:

```
command=/bin/bash -c "sleep %(process_num)02d && virtualenv/bin/python3 manage.py rqworker --name %(program_name)s_my-rq-worker_%(process_num)02d default low"
```

Basically, before running the python command, I sleep for N second, where N is the process number, which basically means I supervisor will start one rq-worker process every second.